# I downloaded the ubuntu iso and burnt to CD, I have folders but there was no front end to install the program on my system. How do I load it?

Tags: boot

I have windows Vista and XP
I downloaded Ubuntu 21.04 and Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS
burnt both to dvd but could not find a front end to install on my computer.
What do I need to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "front end"?

Comment: CD's are no longer large enough, DVD'd are required, however I have not used an optical disk to install Ubuntu in ten years. USB's are quicker, cheaper and more convenient. In windows try Rufus, https://rufus.ie/en_US/ or Etcher, https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: You also won't find a GUI frontend in Windows to 'install' Ubuntu - Wubi which used that mechanism is long since dead.  You will also need to *boot* to the install media, because your only way to install is to dual boot - install Ubuntu alongside Windows - and then boot to Windows or Ubuntu depending on which you need.

Comment: See @user535733's answer. You need to ~reboot~ with the DVD in the slot.

Answer (score 2):

You must shutdown Windows, and then boot from the DVD you created. That's why you created a *bootable* DVD.

Installing Ubuntu requires that your HDD/SSD partitions are not mounted, so the Ubuntu installer can repartition.